# Generate random Numbers with Specific need

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, numbers

I am developing Cocos 2D game.
Please Mention Below Arrangement.

```
---------------------------------|
      |       |          |       |
      |       |          |       |
---------------------------------|
      |       |          |       |
      |       |          |       |
---------------------------------|
      |       |          |       |
      |       |          |       |
---------------------------------|



---------------------------------|
      |        |          |      |
      |        |          |      |
---------------------------------|
```

Now, I need to generate numbers between `1-99` in Upper Block so, When user touch the numbers they dropped into below block. And I have to check for is that numbers make any combination of operation(i.e. +,-, *,/) Thus it divided by 10 or not?

For example if user choose numbers like 3,2,7,8 Then I have internally calculated `(3 +2 +7 +8 = 20 so 20%10 == 0 so number is divisible by 10 so increase score)`, Same thing for -, *,/.
Math operator is will be same but I have to decide by some code that what user has think for dragging numbers.

So my question is how to generate that numbers in upper block that most probably support calculation(Any one of +,-,*,/) for combinations of them give dividability by 10?

Numbers are not such like any combinations(Either +, -, * ,/) of them thus they did not give answer which have modulo 0 to 10.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an inefficient algorithm. Repeatedly generating numbers then testing to see if they pass your condition

```
do
{
   a = random();
   b = random();
   c = random();
   d = random();
 } while( !test(a,b,c,d) );
```

This simplifies the logic. You do need to ensure that at least some combination will work or you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: It's better to use arc4random() function instead of random().

Comment: @[salix alba](http://stackoverflow.com/users/865481/salix-alba) I need to generate 3x4 = 12 random numbers per scene, So applying this analogy would be efficient in my case?

Comment: Yes there may be a better random number generator, its meant more as psudo-code. 

Yes it should be efficient enough. You can generate several million random numbers per second so time should not be an issue.

Comment: better yet: arc4random_uniform() ... also you want to ensure that each random value is in the 0-20 range otherwise the test will succeed very rarely

Comment: @LearnCocos2D IS there any suggestions from you regarding to this question?

Comment: Not really, I think it's a complex problem. I re-read the question, so you definitely will want to randomize each value between 0-99. Ensuring at least one combination fits can be done by randomizing 2 values (ie 17, 22) and then giving the other two values the value needed to round them up to a factor 10 (ie 3 and 8). Now once you have these two "padding" values, you can just increase them by 10 randomly to spread them out across the range, ie 33 and 18 would also work.

Comment: Calculating 3 numbers and then working out the other number will work.   There can be subtle bias problems: it might tend to be smaller than the other numbers.

Comment: @Salixalba, I cant exactly get you. Can you elaborate it?